# Limiting Photo Uploads per User in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having a problem with my heroku web server where a user clicks the photo upload button repeatedly and overloads the server.  This is my basic code for stopping the upload if one is already in progress.

```
def create
  cache_key = "photo_uploads_from_#{request.remote_ip}"
  upload_in_progress = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key)
  if upload_in_progress.nil?
    Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 31.seconds) do
      true
    end
  else
    return
  end

  photo = Photo.new photo_params.slice(:remote_image_url, :image, :notes)

  if photo.save
    render json: photo, status: :created
  else
    render json: { errors: photo.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
  Rails.cache.delete cache_key
end
```

I use a 31 second timeout as heroku has a hard 30 second limit on requests.  I'm just wondering if returning nothing the way I am will be problematic.  Not sure how the multiple concurrent post requests function.

Comment: Have you considered using a javascript debouncer instead? Basically you create an event handler which throttles clicks on the UI element / form submissions.

Comment: Why don't you disable the upload button on the client side using javascript ?

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as @AlexanderLuna. onclick, remove the button from the DOM entirely, or disable it.

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting multiple requests from the same IP address so I figured a back end solution would work better.